# unable to get the client IP for a java EE web service (EDIT: REST) request

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-rs

I'm using glassfish 3.1.2.2 and I don't manage to get the client IP for a web service request.

I have the following member declaration:

```
@Resource
WebServiceContext mWebserviceCtx;
```

However already calling this:

```
MessageContext msgCtx = mWebserviceCtx.getMessageContext();
```

Gets me a NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServiceContextImpl.getMessageContext(WebServiceContextImpl.java:86)
```

Most people asking on this topic complain of a NullPointerException at the next step, when reading from the message context, but I'm not even getting one here... What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: Ass requested, I reduced my code to a little example, a very small example project built from this tutorial and slightly modified:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/giqaa/index.html

I reproduce exactly this error still with this sample code.

```
package helloWorld;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;

@Stateless
@Path("helloworld")
public class HelloWorld {

    @Resource
    WebServiceContext mWebserviceCtx;

    public HelloWorld() {
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getHtml() {
        try {
            MessageContext msgCtx = mWebserviceCtx.getMessageContext();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "<html><body><h1>Hello, World!!</body></h1></html>";
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**: as pointed out in my answer, this is not a web service but a REST service, which was part of my confusion (I assumed the framework would handle both in a similar way in this regard and it turned out not to be the case).

Comment: Please show a brief example of the class (servlet, other?) into which the @Resource is being injected.

Comment: added the code example as requested

Comment: Your solution recognizes that your perception as to the nature of the problem has changed... might want to update the title to match, because fundamentally it's a very different question now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK it seems I found the problem.

It seems I should not be using WebServiceContext because what I am doing is NOT a web service but a REST service. So it was bad terminology from me.

Instead I should use

@Context HttpServletRequest mRequest;

And then mRequest.getRemoteAddr() and this appears to work...